# What are the benefits for claiming authorship on the arXiv?

Tags: authorship, arxiv

When you post an article on the arXiv, it gives the poster a link for co-authors to claim authorship of the paper. I have claimed authorship for most of my articles but some in the beginning of my career were posted by senior collaborators and I have not yet claimed authorship. My name is on the paper, but not in the electronic sense in arXiv's servers. There is also a solo-author paper that arXiv that I submitted but arXiv does not have me registered as the author.

Are there any reasons to try to fix this? What are the benefits to having a complete authorship record on arXiv's servers?